# column is invalid in select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function or group by clause

Tags: java, sql

I have a Java method that looks like this:

```
public ArrayList<Orders> GetOrders(Connection connection, int id) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Orders> feedData = new ArrayList<Orders>();
        ArrayList<Integer> itemsId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT o.id, o.userId FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id join dbo.Users u on o.UserId = u.Id where o.userId = ? group by o.id, o.userId");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Orders o = new Orders();
            o.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT o.ItemId, SUM(price) as price FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id WHERE o.UserId= ? GROUP BY o.id");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs2.next()){
            itemsId.add(rs2.getInt("ItemId"));
            //total = total + rs2.getInt("price");

            }
            o.setItem(itemsId);
            o.setUserId(rs.getInt("userId"));
            o.setTotalAmount(rs2.getInt("total"));
            feedData.add(o);
        }
        return feedData;
    }
    }
```

In the second prepared statement, where I have this query:

```
SELECT o.ItemId, SUM(price) as price FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items
  I on o.itemId = I.id WHERE o.UserId= ? GROUP BY o.id
```

I get above mentioned exception.

i.e

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column 'dbo.Orders.ItemId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You're grouping by `ItemId` (I'd start with lower case letters though) and thus you could get multiple prices which need to be aggregated, e.g. by selecting `sum(price)`. `rs2.getInt("price")` won't work if you select `sum(price)` since there is no selected row called `price`.

Comment: Or remove GROUP BY, do SELECT DISTINCT instead. (If that is what you want...?)

Comment: My primary requirement is to take those selected items and find sum of their prices. I don't see how it solves my requirement.

Comment: Just a side note: you definitely should work on your naming schemes since you're mixing lower case names with upper case names ( `ItemId` vs. `price`) and also have names that don't tell much, e.g. what kind of id is the parameter `id`? Assuming it is user id I'd name it `userId`. Improving your style here will help you and us understand the code and spot errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are selecting `sum(price) as total` in your second snippet, hence the result set column is named `total`. Since you're grouping by item id you get the sum of prices per item and need to do the total calculation yourself or use another query.

Try using `total += rs2.getInt("total");` and `o.setTotalAmount(total)` after the while loop.

Comment: Like I have mentioned, If I take this approach, I get There are no rows in the rowset exception.

Comment: @simarkaur Did you try to manually execute the query to check whether there should be a result or not? The query might be wrong as well as the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the query you are referring to:

```
SELECT ItemId, price
FROM dbo.Orders o join
     dbo.Items I
     on o.itemId = I.id
WHERE o.UserId= ? 
GROUP BY o.id, o.ItemId;
```

Your query does not work because `price` is not in the `group by` clause.

If you want the sum of prices by item, then I would think you want:

```
SELECT o.ItemId, SUM(price) as price
FROM dbo.Orders o join
     dbo.Items I
     on o.itemId = I.id
WHERE o.UserId= ? 
GROUP BY o.ItemId;
```

Comment: I basially want to get sum of prices of items in an order with same order id bought by same user

Answer (score 0):

You've ran into a fundamental requirement of SQL. Any time you have a a "group by" clause, SQL only permits the columns that are groupped on, or aggregates.

The reason is simple: you're groupping on `id`, so there will be a single group per value of `id`, and that translates into a single row in the result of `select` - per value of id. Now supppose there are multiple `itemId`values for given `id`, say the rows with `id` = 5 have `itemId` values of 10, 20 and 30.

The SQL engine cannot put 3 different values into one row!

And that's why, when you do `group by` the select result can only include columns from `group by` and aggregates.

(Some databases relax this requirement a little, and it leads to really messy and hard to understand results)